# php not storing the right value into the database

Tags: php, mysql, post, get

So I need php to store $aid, which should be the ID of the article that the user is currently commenting on, however it always saves it as 0, and for example when I'm on the page localhost/article.php?article_id=69 and write echo $aid; it will echo out 69, but when I want to store it into the database, it just stores it as 0

```
if (isset($_GET['article_id'])) {

include("mySQLcon.inc.php");
$aid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['article_id']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM front_articles WHERE id = '$aid'";
$sql = mysql_query($query); 

}

while ($articles = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {
?>
<div id="IApage">
<?php
echo '<b>' . $articles->title.'</b>'.'<br>'.
             $articles->message. '<br>';
?>
</div>
<?php
}
if(isset($_COOKIE['user'])){
?>
<div id="article_comment_form">
<form id="arti_com_form" name="article_com_for" method="post" action="article.php">  
    <textarea name="comment" rows="7" cols="50"></textarea><br>
    <input name="com_submit" type="submit" value="Comment"/>
</form>
</div>
<?php
}
if (isset($_POST['com_submit'])) {
  $comment_message = $_POST['comment'];
    $comment_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO front_article_comments (article_id, poster_id, poster_username, message, date) VALUES ('$aid', '$poster_id', '$username', '$comment_message', NOW())");
}
echo $aid;
?>
```

Comment: You should avoid using the mysql_ functions as they are now deprecated. You'll want to lookup PDO or use mysqli instead.

Comment: you use mysql_real_escape_string on aid, I recommend changing it to also casting to (int) as this will ensure data integrity. `$aid = (int)$_GET['article_id'];` hackers can only choose numbers, which are not a problem as they are not sql.

Comment: If someone puts a `'` in their comment your code won't work. http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: @Kris To get this working in my demo, I had to set $poster_id, $username, and $_COOKIE['user'] to static values. Where are these being set in your actual code? This code worked for me and inserted data into my table: http://codepad.org/Kv9GS4CC

Results after posting:

```
> mysql> select * from front_article_comments;
> +----+------------+-----------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------------+
> | id | article_id | poster_id | poster_username | message           | date                |
> +----+------------+-----------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------------+
> |  1 |          1 |         1 | Chris           | This is a comment | 2013-10-04 21:32:00 |
> +----+------------+-----------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

**ORIGINAL**:
Your code is posting back to article.php with no value for article_id. The net result is that $_GET['article_id'] is empty, which is where you set $aid. You'll also want to escape the contents of the comment. Try this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['article_id'])) {

include("mySQLcon.inc.php");
$aid = (int)$_GET['article_id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM front_articles WHERE id = ".$aid;
$sql = mysql_query($query); 

}

while ($articles = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {
?>
<div id="IApage">
<?php
echo '<b>' . $articles->title.'</b>'.'<br>'.
             $articles->message. '<br>';
?>
</div>
<?php
}
if(isset($_COOKIE['user'])){
?>
<div id="article_comment_form">
<form id="arti_com_form" name="article_com_for" method="post" action="article.php?article_id=<?php echo $aid; ?>">  
    <textarea name="comment" rows="7" cols="50"></textarea><br>
    <input name="com_submit" type="submit" value="Comment"/>
</form>
</div>
<?php
}
if (isset($_POST['com_submit'])) {
    $comment_message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);
    $comment_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO front_article_comments (article_id, poster_id, poster_username, message, date) VALUES (".$aid.", ".$poster_id.", '".$username."', '".$comment_message."', NOW())");
}
echo $aid;
?>
```

Comment: I think this is the most accurate guess, because I also forgot to mention that $poster_id is also a int in the database, however it saves the correct ID, however I tried out your code and it didn't work...

Comment: I'm creating a corresponding database to try this firsthand instead of making assumptions.

Comment: Edited my post and linked to code that I verified worked. Removing the article_id=# from the form action resulted in warnings and no value stored in my db.

Answer (score 4):

If **article_id** is of type *INT* in your database and you feed it a *STRING*, it will insert as 0.

Try removing the single quotes.

Also, if you plan to ever upgrade your PHP, get used to using PDO sooner than later so you wont have to go back and change everything when you eventually decide to upgrade.

Comment: Why does no error show up? I always thought that error appears in such situations

Comment: What do I save it as then?

Comment: Wherever you have piece of code like this: `'$aid'` change it to `$aid`

Comment: @Fuv is correct on how to fix it. And it is normal that no errors are reporting, this is the behavior of mySQL

Answer (score 2):

You probably have your `id` field in database as `int` . But using single quotes made the `id` string.

Since that is not the case, the string is automatically converted to 0.

Removing the single quotes is the best and i see only option!

**EDIT**
Maybe you should ON the error reporting and see if you have any warnings/errors? So that we get the thing?

Comment: The code posts back to article.php so the value for article_id is not being carried between page loads... While this may be a factor, the value for $aid has never been set based on OP code.

Comment: @ChrisRasco clearly `$aid` has been set, shown by his successful `echo $aid`

Comment: Not clearly. Re-read the post. "when I'm on the page localhost/article.php?article_id=69 and write echo $aid; it will echo out 69, but when I want to store it into the database, it just stores it as 0" In the first instance he's set it manually in the URL. When he submits the form, his destination page is article.php, not article.php?article_id=69. How and when does $aid get set if you go to  article.php ?

Comment: @ChrisRasco : I've a feeling that the code he's posting is of article.php ?

Comment: The reason it is being stored as 0 has already been established, and it is not because it isn't set.

Comment: Yeah, this GET value is automatically resent. You do not need to care about it.

Comment: @cipher I would assume that as well. The first line of the code checks for $_GET['article_id'] and then sets that to $aid. So if $_GET['article_id'] isn't set, such as if you were to visit article.php with no url parameters, $aid is never set. You follow?

Comment: @ChrisRasco Then that would have led to errors on the `while` statement, eh?

Comment: @cipher Not an error, but a warning: Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource.

Comment: "Some conversions occur implicitly. For example, MySQL automatically converts numbers to strings as necessary, and vice versa." - I guess that this given solution is not a solution at all here :)

Comment: @Fuv yeah, i am starting to guess that myself too

Answer (score 0):

Try and change this line

```
 $comment_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO front_article_comments (article_id, poster_id, poster_username, message, date) VALUES ('$aid', '$poster_id', '$username', '$comment_message', NOW())");
```

into

```
 $comment_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO front_article_comments (article_id, poster_id, poster_username, message, date) VALUES ($aid, '$poster_id', '$username', '$comment_message', NOW())");
```

as you can see I took the quotations around $aid away, because I'm guessing it's an integer.